# Запрос параметров у пользователя из метода веб-сервиса

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть asmx веб-сервис. При работе одного из методов нужно уточнить параметры у пользователя, и в зависимости от выбранного варианта, продолжить выполнение метода. Есть ли какие-нибудь шаблоны для данной ситуации? Проект web forms

Comment: Метод не предусматривает двухсторонний обмен, двухсторонний обмен с предложениями и.т.п предусмаривает - **протокол** обмена. Возможно можно делать переменное число параметров. Или xml-параметр с сериализированым классом принимать.

Comment: @nick_n_a, а можно поподробнее?

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, приведите ваши способы. Если asmx отвечает на нечно похожее на post запрос - никто не мешает вернуть вам строку "OK" или строку "Уточните параметр a1 и a5". Угадать какая у вас задача - врядли кому получится.